# Excel VBA input error

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

I'm a business student who just started to learn VBA. I am trying to write a macro for a project but only have minimal experience actually stepping into the code.  What I am trying to do is delete all row entries which have future month's dates in them, and I'd like for this to update based on the current month. I hope I am using the correct functions, but maybe just in the wrong order.

I'm trying to compare the data for each row (in this case I'm looking at cell 16 in each) and I was thinking that if the month digits for the date in that column are greater than the value of the month digits for the current month, then it should delete, but I'm receiving the error [Run-time error '5'   Invalid procedure call or argument].

So here is the part of the code I am having trouble with:

```
If DatePart(mm, Cells(iCntr, 16)).Value > DatePart(mm, Date).Value Then
    Rows(iCntr).Delete
```

In the code, I was only focusing on the month portion because the file I'm using only contains current year information, so I wouldn't have to worry about accidentally failing to delete something for March of next year (03/2017) due to it being June of this year (for example, technically 03/13/2017 would not be deleted since 03 < 06).

---

(Second question for my own learning experience--someone suggested I use iCntr in this, but what does this actually do for the formula?)

---

Update:  Went to Code Review and they updated my code and now the problem I am running into is that the friend who sent me the file left some rows of blanks that contain a single space, which is causing an error when I run the macro.  Could someone suggest how to use the `trim()` function to eliminate those?

```
Sub Remove_excess_entries()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 10000
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 12).Value = "Mule" Or Cells(iCntr, 11).Value = "*R1*" Or Cells(iCntr, 11).Value = "*R2*" Or Cells(iCntr, 7).Value = "*Mule*" Or Cells(iCntr, 6).Value = "*Unassigned*" Or Cells(iCntr, 12).Value = "PS" Or Cells(iCntr, 7).Value = "Marketing" Or Cells(iCntr, 12).Value = "V1" Or DatePart("m", Cells(iCntr, 16).Value) > DatePart("m", Date) Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Also I apologize if I asked this in the wrong place, I'm new to stack overflow via a friend

Comment: `iCntr` would be a variable containing the Row number. You don't need to name it that, it can be anything. If you are not setting that value then you will get an error. As a test, replace `iCntr` with a hard-coded number of a row and see if your code works.

Comment: You could make it easier on yourself and just use the `Month()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iCntr` isn't a VBA command, it's likely just a declared variable (possibly a counter value for iterating over the range of rows you want to consider, based on the context of the code shown).  Presumably you have it declared somewhere and defined in a `For` type loop?

Secondly, [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251733(v=office.15).aspx) the correct parameter for "month" in `DatePart` is "m", not mm.  That means your code should read as:

```
If DatePart("m", Cells(iCntr, 16).Value) > DatePart("m", Date) Then Rows(iCntr).Delete
```

You also have the `.Value` outside the closing brackets, which means you are trying to assign it to the `DatePart` object rather than the `Cells` one.  Feel free to ask anything further if I've not explained it well enough

Comment: Thanks for the information!  The code now works, but it runs very slowly.  Is there a reason it takes a while?  Or a way to speed it up/change the code to increase the speed?  Sorry, I don't know too much about these processes

Comment: Can't say much about that without seeing the rest of your code - one line doesn't really give a lot of information about its efficiency.  Take a look at [codereview.se] and post the whole code there; they'll soon speed you up if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

as for the correct use of `DatePart()` function, type:

```
If DatePart("m", Cells(iCntr, 16)) > DatePart("m", Now) Then Rows(iCntr).Delete
```